# String Variable for Value_If_True returns Row Range in Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use `IF(And()` construct in a `R1C1` Formula to populate a large range of cells. To do this I've created a loop that creates a string variable for the Value_if_True part of the formula, however when the formula runs cells lists a range instead of the contents of the variable

```
v = 1
cs = 71
ce = 87
For c = cs To ce Step 2
    r = "R" & v
    drop.Range(Cells(8, c), Cells(LR, c)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC3>=RC[-18],RC3<=RC[-17])," & r & ","""")"
    v = v + 1
Next
```

I declare the variables at the top of the sub porocedure (r is a String). This is what the cell appears as after I run the macro:

```
=IF(AND($C8>=BA8,$C8<=BB8),8:8,"")
```

The Figure **8:8** should be "**R1**".

Comment: `R1` would be change to 1:1 and `R8` would become 8:8.  You are iterating v so each time it loops the Row output would increase.  What are you wanting as the Output, `R1`? not the row, but the actual string?

Comment: How about r.value? still, I think you would need to use something like indirect here, in principle the value of your variable is R1, not the value in the cell RI. you could also try - " & .Range(r) & " in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want the literal string `"R1"` as the result of the If but when unquoted, it is being referenced as an xlR1C1 range reference.

```
drop.Range(Cells(8, c), Cells(LR, c)).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(AND(RC3>=RC[-18], RC3<=RC[-17]), """ & r & """, TEXT(,))"
```

`TEXT(,)` is just an easy way to say `""` without having to write `""""`.